# How can I turn an Arc<Result<T, E>> into an Arc<Option<T>>?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Is it possible to implement this function correctly?

```
        fn ok<T, E>(arc: Arc<Result<T, E>>) -> Arc<Result<T, ()>> {
            // ?
        }
```

My use case is that I want to pass the `Result` into a function that doesn't know or care about the error type for the result. Which seems like a main use case for `result.ok()` but I can't get it to work for `Arc`. Any attempt to dereference the arc and repackage its `T` leads (understandably) to a `cannot move out of Arc` compiler error.

**UPDATE**: hoping to do this without cloning the underlying data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Arc` provides "shared ownership", i.e. it allows multiple places to hold onto some data without being tied to the lifetime of any particular stack frame.

So in short, yes, it's possible to do this, but you will need to clone the underlying data, so something like:

```rust
fn convert<T: Clone, E: Clone>(arc: Arc<Result<T, E>>) -> Arc<Option<T>> {
    // explicit types added for clarity
    let result: &Result<T, E> = arc.as_ref();
    let cloned_result: Result<T, E> = Result::clone(result);
    Arc::new(cloned_result.ok())
}
```

But this might not be what you want, since these `Arc`s are now pointing to different underlying data; changes to the `Arc<Result<T, E>>` instances will not be reflected in `Arc<Option<T>>` instances.

If you are the author of the function you're passing it into, perhaps that function could be made be generic over its error parameter? If it truly doesn't care about the type of the error, this shouldn't cause any issues, otherwise you might need to add some trait bounds.

Comment: Is there a way to go from `Arc<Result<A, B>>`, to `Result<Arc<A>, Arc<B>>`?

Comment: I ended up using the solution of making the function I'm calling generic over the error parameter. Thanks for cracking the X Y problem for this question.

Comment: Update: the generic-error-parameter trick worked, but I refactored to make the function that produces an `Arc<Result<A, B>>` *instead* return a `Result<Arc<A>, Arc<B>>`. This enables simply using `.ok()` on the `Result` to go from the `Result<_, _>` to `Option<Arc<A>>`.